# java sum two arrays+move the carry but index[0] wont display the last digit properly

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I created a program for adding two arrays and moving the carry to the next index position , it works but when it gets to the last value index[0] if a carry is coming example: 5+6 =11 + 1(carry) = 12, i'll get in position [0] only the number 2. not the whole number 12. how can i stop the carry if it reaches to index [0] and just display the whole number?
(decimal system only)

public class SumArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = 2;
    int [] arr1 = new int [size];
    int [] arr2 = new int [size];   
    int [] result = new int [2];

    System.out.println("Array 1 : ");
    for(int i =0; i<arr1.length; i++){  
        System.out.print("Position : " + i + " = "  );
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println("Array 2 : ");
    for(int i =0; i<arr2.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Position : " + i + " = "  );
        arr2[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
    //carry sum
        boolean toggle = false;

        for(int i=result.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            int sum=0;
            int temp=0;
            int carry=10;
            sum = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
            if (toggle == true) {
                if ( sum >= carry) {        
                temp = sum+1 - carry;
                }
                else {
                     temp = sum+1;
                }
            }
                else if (sum > carry) {
                    temp = sum - carry;
                }
                else{
                    temp = sum;
                }
            result[i] = temp;
            toggle = sum >= carry ;
        }   
    System.out.println("Final Array : " + Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

}

Comment: Your code doesn't even work for the case when there is no carry, for e.g.,
 [12,12]+[12,12]=[15,14]. How you want to handle the case when 2 or more carries are coming on a non-zero index, for e.g., [9,199]+[4,199]? Update your question to provide clarity on what exactly you want to achieve with some examples.

Comment: i know it is only for decimal number system, you can come up with a solution on my problem and not throwing your negative attitude as you know it all, it seems, thanks for your concern, and yes the code works. Thanks and any help is appreciated